# how can i add subrow when didselectRowAt ( Swift 3)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, expand

I want to add a sub row in row at index path with custom cell without using a library.

When I select a cell, another cell appears below this cell, this operation is repeated for each cell
Ps: the cell of which it will appear it is the same

I try this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {            
        return arrayEnum.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       var CellTB: UITableViewCell!

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "enumCell", for: indexPath)as! UserFlagTableViewCell
            cell.UserflagLabel.text = arrayEnum[indexPath.row].rawValue
            CellTB = cell


//           let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "freeTextCell", for: indexPath)as! FreeTextTableViewCell
//            cell1.sendButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("sendUserflagEvent:"), for: .touchUpInside)
//            CellTB = cell1


              return CellTB

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: UserFlagType.userFlagTypes.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)



        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()


    }
```

i have 1 section 
i have 6 rows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding 1 to your array.count

```
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: array.count+1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

Add 1 more object to this array, because if not, you will get an error saying that you are trying to get more rows than your datasource array.

So:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//Add a row here to your array
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: array.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

should work.

Comment: no it's not working for me and how can i show the new cell ??
reason: 'attempt to insert row 6 into section 0, but there are only 6 rows in section 0 after the update'
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: IndexPath starts from 0, and you are doing array.count, that starts from 1. so... you have to do array.count - 1. I'll edit the answer, sry

Comment: i have a list of enum ( 6 enum ) i make it in table view and i want when i select a cell a new custom cell appear ( how i have a button and text to send ) . i don't know how do it . and i cant add to may enum array

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are doing correct just insert  the new element in the arrayEnum and then

tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:CurrentIndex , section: 0)], with: .automatic)
 tableView.endUpdates()

Here CurrentIndex in an index of element where you want to insert an element in array , it will automatically reflect in tableview